# Should I use bulk action or allow individual actions on the Dashboard?

Tags: gui-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, notification, dashboard

On the dashboard, I have an "Actions Required" section. I would like some feedback about user behaviour when being affected by length of time and number of items to manage.

In the "Actions Required" section, there is a list of people who are invited to the site and I wanted to remind the user to either remove invitee from list or send a 1-click notification to remind invitee to respond.

So in cases where there aren't many people to remove, it's easy for the user to remove individually, but if they had to remove 15 people, then they would need bulk removal.

Also, if the invitation was sent 5 days ago, maybe the user would want to just follow up instead of removing it. However, if the invitation was sent out 3 weeks ago, would there be a higher chance users want to completely clear the list or would they still want the option to remove per case/invitee?

How should I approach these scenarios, and what actions should I allow?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few things they would want to do -

1. Remove/Remind All
2. Remove/Remind All but few
3. Remove/Remind only specific

So to answer your question, provide solutions which cater to solve all of the above. Something of this sort -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**You should provide both.**

Give the user the ability to remove/remind single entries while also giving him the option to mark multiple entries and remove/remind them all together.

Answer (score 1):

Allow for as many scenarios as you can without cluttering up your UI.

If you think there might be a chance that users will want to make bulk changes... then make it an option. Bulk change option is there to save the user time and effort which is definitely positive UX.